# Navigator error with context what is the reason for the announcement,

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JECG.png)

error text: Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps.dartuse_build_context_synchronously

```
I don't understand the reason for the announcement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stateFulWidget when you use `async - await` you have to confirm that next widgets are mounted in Navigation.

So for that you have to add condition for mounted widget

```
 if (!mounted) return;
 Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ElectionInfo(),
 ));
```